# PHP function_exists() returns false for empty()

Tags: php

Why does `function_exists("empty")`return false?

```
if (function_exists("empty")) {
    echo "Not working";
}
```

Documentation states the following for `function_exists`:

> Checks the list of defined functions, both built-in (internal) and user-defined, for function_name.

As far as I know `empty` is a defined and built-in function.

Comment: This is where reading the actual [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) helps: empty() is ___not___ a function, it is a language construct

Comment: @MarkBaker No need to be cheeky

Answer (score 5):

Empty is not a function.
According to manual:

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it
> cannot be called using variable functions.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: Is there any way to check if it exists?

Comment: @MarkBaker Of course, but I'm writing a validation class that can take any php function and execute it with a specfied value. So I have to check that the function exists...

Comment: @lawls Consider using call_user_func() or call_user_func_array() in this case, it will return === false in case the function does not exist.